# SonarQube - Two methods with same method signature but not providing classes

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube Server Environment details as follows:

```
OS – CentOS-7.6
SonarQube Version – 6.7.7(LTS).
Database – MYSQL - 5.7.25
```

From `sonar.log` file I can see the below messages.

```
Two methods with same method signature but not providing classes assignable? "public abstract boolean java.util.List.isEmpty()" and "public boolean java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty()" please report!
```

Should I need to fix this errors or I can ignore?

Comment: It looks like a bug. See [here](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/929) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621484/java-msg-in-console-two-methods-with-same-method-signature-but-not-providing-c).